# Giving Ubuntu Desktop a domain name to ssh into

Tags: ssh, ip, hostname

I know absolutely nothing about remote access to a desktop. I've just set up a machine with Ubuntu installed which I wish to run calculations on remotely.

I've installed openssh-server and opened port 22. I can now successfully access the desktop remotely using the command

```
ssh username@IPADDRESS
```

But I have a couple of questions:

1) Since this machine is connected to a network, I'm worried the IP address may change - how do I make it static?

2) (And more importantly). It would be a lot easier if it wasn't an IP address used to ssh to the machine. How do I change it from an IP address to something like:

```
ssh username@MACHINENAME.university.address
```

Some machines here already have this set up but I'm not quite sure how to do it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Read this to get a static IP:  https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Configuring_the_interface_manually

Let's assume you got the static IP 192.168.1.22

And then on your computer, enter this line in /etc/hosts:

```
192.168.1.22        MACHINENAME.university.address MACHINENAME
```

And you can access via either MACHINENAME.university.address or MACHINENAME from your computer.